# Uploading a library module to Bintray but the jar put the files under app module package name

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm following [this guide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) to upload my custom view library onto bintray maven repo. I skip the GPS signing steps since I wouldn't need them. My sample module is named "*com.aungkyawpaing.currencytextviewsample*" and library module is named "*com.aungkyawpaing.currencytextview*".

Adding the module as local dependency works but after I upload to bintray maven and import again, the custom view went under "*com.aungkyawpaing.currencytextviewsample*" which is app module package name. Here's [my repo on github](https://github.com/vincent-paing/CurrencyTextView)

I think it's a problem in install and bintray gradle file since it's work locally but I'm not sure. I tried googling and browse through a lot of tutorial but there's no mention of this issue yet.